# highlighting entire row based on today's year and month columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns Year and Month as below in my excel. I would like to highlight entire row based on two columns Year and Month. So, whenever I open the excel, the current row is highlighted.
For example, if I open the excel today, it should already highlight the current row for 2022,November and when I open in december, it should already highlight 2002,december. Like wise, I have data for several years. I tried searching for the answers, most are telling how to highlight rows and columns on selection. But here I need the highlighting to be done automatically based on year and month.

[image]

Please suggest how to perform this.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

My conditional formatting rule is based on this formula:

```
=ROW(A2)-1=MONTH(TODAY())
```

But if you have data for several years probably you'll need the CF rule to be applied to **all** rows in worksheet and that's a **terrible** idea because CF rules can really overcharge files.